# Two Columns With Flexible Scroll Overflow

Tags: html, css, web

I have a two column layout. The left column is a list of repeated messages and the right column several different menus. I want the two columns to always be the same height as the right column and the messages in the left column should overflow to scroll.  There is also a header in the left column that should not scroll.

The problem is that without explicitly setting the height of the scroll `div` it will expand to contain all spans and never overflow. How do I make the left column the same hight as the right with the overflow scrolling?  For an example of what I want, uncomment the `height:120px` line in `.scroll`. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s38ax4nq/)

Here is a mock up of the basic structure

```
<div class='table'>
<div id='c1' class='column'>
    <h4>Column 1</h4>
    <div class='scroll'>
        <span></span><span></span><span></span>
        <span></span><span></span><span></span>
        <span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='c2' class='column'>
    <h4>Column 2<h4>
</div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
div.table {
    display:table;
    width:500px;
}

div.table div.column {
    display:table-cell;
}

#c1 {background-color:blue;}
#c2 {background-color:red; height:150px;}

.scroll {
    background-color:#ccc;
    overflow-y:auto;
    //height:120px;
}

.scroll span {
    height:28px;
    background-color: #999;
    display:block;
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

I am trying to do it without any **JS** - but I may have to use it. I tried a solution using `display:flex` but was unable to get that as close as this one.

**Edit:** I don't actually know the height of the right column. It changes based on dynamically generated content - and can grow if someone expands menus.  I want to the left column to stay fixed to the right columns height with the overflow scrolling.  I've updated the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s38ax4nq/2/

Comment: what I really don't understand is, you're setting the right element a height of 150px... What stops you (since you know and have a defined height) to set the same to the left one?

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.table {
  display: table;
  width: 500px;
}
div.table div.column {
  display: table-cell;
}
#c1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#c2 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
}
.scroll {
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 150px;
}
.scroll span {
  height: 28px;
  background-color: #999;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div id='c1' class='column'>
    <h4>Column 1</h4>
    <div class='scroll'>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='c2' class='column'>
    <h4>Column 2</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can change your `css` like..

```
.scroll {
    background-color:#ccc;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:150px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should make my example more complex. The height:150px is there just for simplicity. I don't actually know the height - and it may change as the user expands  menu dialogues.